# Remove or hide LayersControl

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-leaflet

I want to remove or hide LayersControl because I change the layer of the map with an external menu. Is this possible? I have this code:

> HTML

```
<div leaflet 
     [leafletOptions]="leafletOptions"
     [leafletBaseLayers]="baseLayers"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
</div>
```

> TS

```
  leafletOptions: L.MapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoomControl: false,
    center: L.latLng(40.4166395, -3.7046087)
  };

  baseLayers: { [layerName: string]: L.Layer } = {
    'OSM': this.mapService.baseMaps.OSM,
    'Catastro': this.mapService.baseMaps.Catastro
  };
```

How can I do so that the map does not show me the box that allows me to change the base layer? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : I can do it with CSS styles, but if there is a better way I prefer it

Comment: I don't think there's currently a really clean way to do this with the way we set up the directives in ngx-leaflet. Your best bet for now is to either add your baselayers manually as layers using the [layer] binding, or to manually remove it by accessing the control manually using injection or via CSS. I'll try to put together an example when I get a chance. Also, feel free to put in a feature request on the ngx-leaflet GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
map.layerscontrol.removeFrom(map);
```

I assume layerscontrol was initialized as follows:

```
layerscontrol = L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

Doc: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layer-removefrom